# vimclojure doesn't respect #_ commented lines

Tags: vim, clojure

Even though it says it does in the release notes for V 2.1.2 (which was quite a while ago). Obviously the code runs as it should, but it's distracting to have these forms syntax colored as though they were  uncommented code. Does anyone have this working or know how to fix it?

Comment: emacs's clojure mode does this as well. It seems to be on purpose.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Didn't have one, or I would have.

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting `#_` correctly is hard. Since `#_ 5` comments the `5` and `#_ (foo)` comments `(foo)` one has to highlight arbitrary expressions. Which may be separated from `#_` by arbitrary whitespace. I never had enough pain to make it work. I'm not even sure, that Vim's highlighting capabilities are sufficient.

The issue tracker is [here](https://bitbucket.org/kotarak/vimclojure/issues). However VimClojure's development is officially frozen. You might want to consider using the [newer plugins](https://github.com/guns/vim-clojure-static).

Comment: I see; I was looking at the github mirror of the repository, that's why I couldn't find the issues list.

I do respect that doing #_ correctly is not trivial. I'll check out the newer plugins and submit there if needed.

Cheers